# How do 'Get X votes/views' badges work?

Tags: support, badges

If you get 100 upvotes on an question or answer, that'll get you a Great Question/Answer badge. Likewise, there's the Famous Question badge for question views. But what happens if you already have a Nice/Good Answer? Does the lower-level badge get replaced, or does it stay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [description for the Nice Answer badge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/45/nice-answer) says:

> This badge can be awarded multiple times.

You earn a new one each time you meet its requirements, for each answer that meets it. Your gold or silver badge never 'replaces' your bronze badge: you get it in addition. I still have a Nice Answer badge for each of my answers that also earned me a Good Answer badge, and both of those for the answers that gave me Great Answer badges.

If you click on your badges, you'll see which answers you earned them for.

Comment: Basic mechanic: badges are only added, never removed.